# Move website from XAMPP to web server

Tags: apache, upload, server, xampp

This may be trivial, but I would like to know how you guys would go about this.
So I was making a website for a department of my university this summer, and now is the time I have to move all the source files and database files from XAMPP directory onto the server. I've got the access to the server through VPN and remote desktop. Now, I am not sure whether to install Apache, phpMyAdmin, MySQL etc. on the server and overwrite single configuration files (e.g. php.ini), or if I could simply move my entire XAMPP folder onto the server. I am using Windows 10 and the server is Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to actually install PHP, MySQL, and Apache to the server directly; simply copying the files from your computer won't install the corresponding system files or services or anything like that. Whether you use XAMPP or install them individually yourself, it's just like most other software that needs to be installed properly in order to function. Then, of course, you can copy over the relevant files that you've changed such as the configuration files and your site.